# Draw grid and marker on google maps quickly: by dragging and dropping

Tags: google-maps

Is there any utility/software to draw grid on google maps and put marker in the center of each cell in the grid..

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps. Adjust the 'gridsize' variable to the degrees you need for your grid.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fcoramos/kw1jpz5h/6/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" ></script>
<script>
var map,
    myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33,-71),
    gridstyle = { strokeColor: 'yellow', strokeWeight: 1 };  
    grid = [],
    markers = []

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:4,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    scaleControl:true };

  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapProp);

  var gridsize = 5; //Grid size in degrees

  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed', function() {
      var gridline,
          gridlat,
          gridlon,
          n = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
          s = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
          e = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(), 
          w = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()

       // If a previous grid and markers are set, we remove them.
       if (grid.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) { grid[i].setMap(null);  }
        }     

        if (markers.length > 0)
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { markers[i].setMap(null); }
        }

      var sgrid = Math.round(s/gridsize)*gridsize;
      var wgrid = Math.round(w/gridsize)*gridsize;

      // Here we create the grid.
      for (gridlat = sgrid; gridlat < n; gridlat = gridlat + gridsize)
         {
          var gridline = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: [{lat: gridlat, lng: e}, {lat: gridlat, lng: w}],
           map: map
           });
           gridline.setOptions(gridstyle);
           grid.push(gridline);
        }

      for (gridlng = wgrid; gridlng < e; gridlng = gridlng + gridsize)
         {
          var gridline = new google.maps.Polyline({
           path: [{lat: n, lng: gridlng}, {lat: s, lng: gridlng}],
           map: map
           });
           gridline.setOptions(gridstyle);
           grid.push(gridline);
        }

     // Here we create the markers.    
     for (markerlat = sgrid+gridsize/2; markerlat < n; markerlat = markerlat + gridsize)
     {
       for (markerlng = wgrid+gridsize/2; markerlng < e; markerlng = markerlng + gridsize)
        {
          var markerposition = {lat: markerlat, lng: markerlng};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: markerposition,
            map: map
          });
          markers.push(marker);
       }
     }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thanks alot fot your answer fco, very usefull. now i want to have grids(boxes) in meter instead of degree, as you wrote ar gridsize = 5; //Grid size in degrees in code. i need to have 1000*1000 m^2 grids. what should i do ? thanks again